# TUI driver to run GFX/GUI programs under text console

Tags: linux, library

I'm looking for display server library/driver as alternative or extension to X11 which can execute GUI applications as CUI (Console User Interface).

Something similar to [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)/[AAlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AAlib) (see: [BB demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ukhOAUseKY)).

I believe it should be implementing the X11 display server protocol as similar to [X virtual framebuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) (Xvfb).

So to aim is to run either X apps (e.g. `xcalc`) or wine emulated GUI apps without need of specifying `DISPLAY` in similar way as [VLC can play videos under aalib](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5JLjfCi0mw), so they can be run on the remote terminal (as alternative solution to Xvfb or X11 forwarding).

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is this project: https://github.com/tombh/texttop

As per the summary, it renders a full Linux X desktop as a TTY stream over SSH.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TE_D_fx_ut8) should give you some idea of what you get.